# ImageView cause slow scroll performances in RecyclerView

Tags: android, performance, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm actually developping an app with Xamarin.Android and I can't get rid of a performance issue with my RecyclerView.

Here's the problem:
I have a RecyclerView displaying Cardviews, only 4.
Each Cardview contains an image which I tried to keep pretty light (65Ko) in an ImageView. Those images are loaded from the drawable res folder at jpg format.

**The scroll is damn laggy !**
I tried to optimize the Cardview's layout as best as I could, and it runs perfectly without Imageviews.

How could I make this smooth WITH the images ?

Here's my RecyclerView:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            local:MvxBind="Visibility InvertedVisibility(IsError)">
    <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource BenchmarkWods; ItemClick WodSelectedCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_benchmarkwod"/>
     </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And this is my CardView template:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:translationZ="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/stock1_small" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="#80000000" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:padding="8dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wod_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wod_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wod_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    local:MvxBind="Text Name"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4CD964"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wod_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some text"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                local:MvxBind="Text Type" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/wod_type_icon"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_person_white_24dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wod_goal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="some text"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            local:MvxBind="Text MetconType" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="some text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see, I already tried to put fixed widths and heights where I could in order to prevent too much processing for the device.

*Also, I've got a bonus question for you:
The CardView elevation is not working at all. Even after browsing the whole web for a solution. If you find what's going on, you're my superhero !*

**EDIT:
(SOLVED)**
All my problems were because of *GPU acceleration* wasn't turned on for my app.

It caused the scroll lag, the elevation issue and the GPU overdraw disfunction.

Comment: Please show yours RecyclerView's implementation code. You should also make your xml a little cleaner, nested layouts inside recyclerview is not a good thing

Comment: Try to keep your xmls as flat as possible, Might I suggest using <include> tag to separate your layouts. Also may you post your java code? because your code implementation may affect performance as well.

Comment: There is not particular java code behind this issue. Also, I noticed a slightly better performance by removing the activity's background and putting a match_parent value to The linearLayout un the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my problems were because of *GPU acceleration* wasn't turned on for my app.

It caused the scroll lag, the elevation issue and the GPU overdraw disfunction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with "overdraw backgrounds", please enable ["Show overdraw areas"](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/dev-options-overdraw.html) in "Developer Options" and check the amount of overdraw on your screen.

Comment: This functionnality is not working on my app for some reasons.. maybe beacause xamarin uses the JVM to render the app

Answer (score 0):

if you use GLIDE Library
add width and height
 and check your image size

```
  Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .thumbnail(0.1f)
            .centerCrop()
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                     holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    return false;
                }
            })

            .override(630, 370)

            .into(holder.image_path);
```